# reverse flatten numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have an array

`[[0, 1, 0, 0] [0, 1, 0, 0] [1, 0, 0, 0] ..., [0, 1, 0, 0] [0, 1, 0, 0]
 [1, 0, 0, 0]]`
of Shape`(38485,)`
i want to reshape to `(38485,4)` like

```
[[0, 1, 0, 0] 
[0, 1, 0, 0] 
[1, 0, 0, 0]
.
.
.
[0, 1, 0, 0]
[0, 1, 0, 0]
[1, 0, 0, 0]]
```

but when i try `array.reshape(-1,4)` it throws me the error `ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 38485 into shape (4)`

My code to get array:

```
dataset = pd.read_csv('train.csv')

y = dataset.iloc[:, 6]

fr=np.array([1,0,0,0])
re=np.array([0,1,0,0])
le=np.array([0,0,1,0])
ri=np.array([0,0,0,1])
for i in range(y.shape[0]):
    if y[i]=="Front":
        y[i]=fr
    elif y[i]=="Rear":
        y[i]=re
    elif y[i]=="Left":
        y[i]=le
    elif y[i]=="Right":
        y[i]=ri

array=y.values
```

Is there any way I can accomplish this?

**I Fixed this by**

`array = np.array([[n for n in row] for row in array])`

Thanks to [wim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/674039/wim)

Comment: What does `set(len(sub_array) for sub_array in array)` return?

Comment: `reshape` cannot change the total number of elements.  38485*4 is larger than the original 38485.  But what is the `dtype` of your array?  Integers or object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The array length must be a multiple of 4.  38485 is not a multiple of 4.  Otherwise, the reshape as you have written it should work correctly:

```
array.reshape(-1,4)
```

Comment: I tried to delete an element from the array to make the size `(38484,)` after reshaping with `array.reshape(-1,4)` I got `(9621, 4)` but I need `(38484,4)`. When I print the array I get all the elements on next to other in the same line, but I need them one below the other, like I mentioned in the question. I'm Sure that every inner array has 4 elements.

Comment: What is the `array.dtype`?

Comment: @wim I'd bet on `object`

Comment: This this:  `array = np.array([[n for n in row] for row in array])` and see if it resolves your problem.

Answer (score 2):

## Updated answer:

The variable `y` is a numpy array which contained strings and `numpy.array`s. Its `dtype` is `object`, so numpy doesn't understand it's a table, even though it's full of 4-element `numpy.array`s at the end of the preprocessing.

You could either avoid mixing object types by using another variable than `y` or convert `y.values` with :

```
array = np.array([x.astype('int32') for x in y.values])
```

As an example:

```
import numpy as np
y = np.array(["left", "right"], dtype = "object")
y[0] = np.array([1,0])
y[1] = np.array([0,1])
print(y)
# [[1 0] [0 1]]
print(y.dtype)
# object
print(y.shape)
# (2,)
y = np.array([x.astype('int32') for x in y])
print(y)
# [[1 0]
#  [0 1]]
print(y.dtype)
# int32
print(y.shape)
# (2, 2)
```

## Original answer:

Your `array` is somehow incomplete. It has 38485 elements, many of which look like 4-elements arrays. But somewhere in the middle, there must be at least one inner-array which doesn't have 4 elements. Or you might have a mix of collections (`list`, `array`, ).

That could be why the second value isn't defined in the shape.

Here's an example with one `(8, 4)` array and a copy of it, with just one element missing:

```
import numpy as np

data = np.array([[0, 1, 0, 0],[0, 1, 0, 0],[1, 0, 0, 0] , [0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0],[1, 0, 0, 0]])
print(data.shape)
# (8, 4)
print(data.dtype)
# int64
print(set(len(sub_array) for sub_array in data))
# set([4])
print(data.reshape(-1, 4))
# [[0 1 0 0]
#  [0 1 0 0]
#  [1 0 0 0]
#  [0 1 0 0]
#  [0 1 0 0]
#  [0 1 0 0]
#  [0 1 0 0]
#  [1 0 0 0]]

broken_data = np.array([[0, 1, 0, 0],[0, 1, 0, 0],[1, 0, 0, 0] , [1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0],[1, 0, 0, 0]])
print(broken_data.shape)
# (8, )
print(broken_data.dtype)
# object
print(set(len(sub_array) for sub_array in broken_data))
# set([3, 4])
print(broken_data.reshape(-1, 4))
# [[[0, 1, 0, 0] [0, 1, 0, 0] [1, 0, 0, 0] [1, 0, 0]]
#  [[0, 1, 0, 0] [0, 1, 0, 0] [0, 1, 0, 0] [1, 0, 0, 0]]]
print([sub_array for sub_array in broken_data if len(sub_array) != 4])
# [[1, 0, 0]]
```

Find the sub-arrays that don't have exactly 4 elements and either filter them out or modify them.

You'll then have a `(38485,4)` array, and you won't have to call `reshape`.

Comment: my `print(set(len(sub_array) for sub_array in broken_data))` prints `{4}` and i'm sure there are no missing values in the inner list.
`print([sub_array for sub_array in broken_data if len(sub_array) != 4])` prints `[]` which proves i have no broken arrays

Comment: Interesting. What about `print(set(type(sub_array) for sub_array in broken_data))`?

Comment: it prints {<class 'numpy.ndarray'>}

Comment: Thanks for the fast answers. What about `print(set(sub_array.dtype for sub_array in broken_data))`? :)

Comment: it prints '{dtype('int32')}' I should the one thanking :)

Comment: Shoot. Then I'm at loss. Your data footprints all look correct.

Comment: @VijayabhaskarJ: How did you build `array`?

Comment: may be because of array.dtype being an obeject? how could i fix that?

Comment: Not sure, I've never encountered this problem before. `array.astype('int32')`?

Comment: my code 
`dataset = pd.read_csv('train.csv')

y = dataset.iloc[:, 6]

fr=np.array([1,0,0,0])
re=np.array([0,1,0,0])
le=np.array([0,0,1,0])
ri=np.array([0,0,0,1])
for i in range(y.shape[0]):
   if y[i]=="Front":
       y[i]=fr
   elif y[i]=="Rear":
       y[i]=re
   elif y[i]=="Left":
       y[i]=le
   elif y[i]=="Right":
       y[i]=ri

array=y.values`

If it looks messy visit [link](http://codepad.org/rpiYcGeB)

Comment: @VijayabhaskarJ: Please add this info the question. Python looks bad in comments :)

Comment: you may visit that link for now,I'm having trouble in editing my question right now

Comment: `array = y.values.astype('int32')` didn't work but `array = np.array([[n for n in row] for row in array])` this worked. Thank you for your time! :)